# Switch-controlled outlet is always hot

Tags: electrical

*I did NOT change any outlets, just the single pole switch that controlled the top plug of the outlets, and a 3 way switch in the same box that had no control over the outlets.*

I have a single pole light switch in my living room that controls the top outlet of three outlets in the room.  To my knowledge it controls nothing else.  The single pole switch shares a box with a three way switch that controls the dining room light.  The outlets have always worked without issue.  We painted and needed to go with all white switches, outlets and covers, so the issue began...

I shut off the power, then replaced the three way switch.  Turned the power on and the three way switch worked fine.  I again shut off the power and then I replaced the single pole switch.  Turned the power back on, and the top outlets are now always hot and the switch does nothing.  Bottom outlet is hot as well.  Shut off power, rewire single pole switch changing which wire went to which screw.  Turn power back on, and again top outlet always hot, along with bottom outlet.  Remove new switch, check wires coming into the switch and both are hot.  The top outlets remain hot when the single pole switch is removed as well.  Shut off power, put OLD switch back in, and problem of top outlet always being hot is still there.  I never changed any of the outlets, only the switch, and returned old switch but problem is still there.

It's like once I disconnected the old switch, no matter what I do, the top outlet stays hot.  I'm not super knowledgeable about this, but it makes no sense to me.  Gotta figure it out, because all my rooms up stairs are wired this way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Outlet in question
[image]

New Single Pole Switch
[image]

Outlet in question
[image]

Inside of box with switches
[image]

New 3 way switch

[image: enter preformatted text here]
[image]

Old 3 way switches...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box and receptacle box in question please?

Comment: I bet a picture of the side of the outlets hot side will tell the tale. Look at the two brass screws on your outlet. Is there a metal tab that is acting like a jumper? snap that off so that the outlets become 2 discrete circuits.

Comment: You don't talk about changing outlets but from your description, you must have. The trick, as Scott mentioned, is that you must snap off one or both side tabs on the outlet, the same way as the old outlet. Failure to that will affect all outlets on that circuit.

Comment: I’ll try to get pics up later today. I did NOT change any outlets, just the single pole switch. That’s what’s so confusing...

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] so you can learn how you can best help us help you. You'll find that this isn't a discussion forum, but a Question & Answer board - only answers should go in the box marked "Answer".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my switch controlled receptacle always on?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/68202/why-is-my-switch-controlled-receptacle-always-on)

Comment: If you just changed a 2 wire switch (2 conductors) how could you mess it up? If there were 2 cables with 2 or more conductors each it is incorrectly wired and a photo or description of the wires will be needed.

Comment: Please go to your original PC and browser that you asked this question from, and register your account via an email, Google or Facebook login.  That will allow you to post pics and comment like normal, and prevent weird stuff from happening.

Comment: How are you determining the switched outlets to be hot? What happens if you remove the switch, put wire nuts on the switch's wires to protect against touching them, and power up the circuit with the switch removed? Are the outlets still live or are they dead?

Comment: Whatsisname - I am determining the outlets are hot because the top and bottom both work regardless of the position of the switch.  Also, when I removed the switch, the outlets are still live.

Comment: I added a few pics.  The outlet was not rewired.  It is the same outlet that has always been there.  The switch is new.  There is a three way switch in the same box, that controls the dining room light opposite a dimmer switch, that was replaced and works fine.  That switch was completed and tested before I touched the single pole, so there was no crossover.  Thanks in advance and I apologize for struggling to figure out how to post and comment properly...

Comment: @PatB. Can you post a photo looking into the back of the switch box please?

Comment: I added a pic of inside the switch box.  Please note, I touched nothing back  there and would have no idea where to start.  I simply replaced the three way switch on the right, and once that was complete replaced single pole switch on left, then returned power to find outlet always on...

Comment: If they are on the same circuit, there *might* be some connection with the three-way switch. Three-way switches are not *always* wired the same. Can you post a picture of the *old* three-way switch, showing the screws and the *new* three-way switch as it is currently wired?

Comment: I added pics of the new 3 way switch wired, that's in the same box as the single pole.  Unfortunately, I do not know which three way switch was originally in the box.  I pulled out a few others before that one and they all went in the same bag, and some of the screws were out.  So I posted pics of a few of the old 3 way switches.  Maybe that can be helpful if they're all the same...

Comment: Do you have a multimeter btw?

Comment: I do not have a multimeter, but if needed I could get one.

Comment: You should edit your question, almost rewrite, and describe everything. You question, the pics, and comments paint a conflicting and confusing story.

Comment: Tried to edit question to make it more clear...

Comment: If still looking for an answer, see other questions about replacing three-way switches. It's clear you miswired something; the instructions there for analyzing the situation should resolve it.